# SpringBoot WebFlux Update List of Object data and return a Mono

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

Im passing a List in the request body and i need to return a Mono as the output response.  But while using flatMap after single update the return statement works and it throws error on the IDE.  Is there any way to achieve this?

ReportController.java

```
  @ApiOperation("This is a POST API for saving active Device details.")
    @PostMapping(value = UrlPaths.ACTIVE_DEVICE_WITH_DISCOUNT)
    public Mono<UserEventsResponseDTO> activeDeviceWithDiscount(
            @Valid @RequestBody List<SelectedEventsForActiveDevicesWithDiscountDTO> userEventsDTOList) {
        logger.info("Devices details....{}", userEventsDTOList);

        return reportService.saveDeviceDetails(userEventsDTOList);
    }
```

ReportServiceImpl.java

```
 @Override
    public Mono<UserEventsResponseDTO> saveDeviceDetails(
            List<SelectedEventsForActiveDevicesWithDiscountDTO> deviceList) {
        final UserEventsResponseDTO responseDTO = new UserEventsResponseDTO();
        final List<SelectedEventsForActiveDevicesWithDiscount> activeDeviceList = new ArrayList<SelectedEventsForActiveDevicesWithDiscount>();
        deviceList.forEach(device -> {
            SelectedEventsForActiveDevicesWithDiscount deviceDetails = new SelectedEventsForActiveDevicesWithDiscount();
            deviceDetails.setAddedOn(device.getAddedOn());
            deviceDetails.setUpdatedOn(device.getUpdatedOn());
            deviceDetails.setContractId(device.getContractId());
            deviceDetails.setCustomerId(device.getCustomerId());
            deviceDetails.setEventName(device.getEventName());
            deviceDetails.setIsSubscribed(device.getIsSubscribed());
            deviceDetails.setMonthYear(device.getMonthYear());
            deviceDetails.setDeviceType(device.getDeviceType());
            deviceDetails.setProfileId(device.getProfileId());
            deviceDetails.setSourceId(device.getSourceId());
            deviceDetails.setDeviceId(device.getDeviceId());
            activeDeviceList.add(deviceDetails);
        });
        logger.info("Device Details...{}", activeDeviceList);
        activeDeviceList.forEach(activeDevice -> {
            String addedOnDate = activeDevice.getAddedOn().split("T")[0];
            logger.info("Added on...{}", addedOnDate);
            String updatedOnDate = activeDevice.getUpdatedOn().split("T")[0];
            logger.info("Updated on....{}", updatedOnDate);
            LocalDate addedOn = LocalDate.parse(addedOnDate);
            LocalDate updatedOn = LocalDate.parse(updatedOnDate);
            String deviceId = activeDevice.getDeviceId();
            logger.info("Device ID...{}", deviceId);
            if (!addedOn.isEqual(updatedOn)) {
                logger.info("It is a new record...{}");
                return activeDevicesRepo.findByDeviceIdAndAddedOn(deviceId, activeDevice.getAddedOn())
                        .flatMap(deviceDetails2 -> {
                            logger.info("Device Details...{}", deviceDetails2);
                            deviceDetails2.setContractId(activeDevice.getContractId());
                            deviceDetails2.setCustomerId(activeDevice.getCustomerId());
                            deviceDetails2.setDeviceId(activeDevice.getDeviceId());
                            deviceDetails2.setDeviceType(activeDevice.getDeviceType());
                            deviceDetails2.setEventName(activeDevice.getEventName());
                            deviceDetails2.setIsSubscribed(activeDevice.getIsSubscribed());
                            deviceDetails2.setMonthYear(activeDevice.getMonthYear());
                            deviceDetails2.setProfileId(activeDevice.getProfileId());
                            deviceDetails2.setSourceId(activeDevice.getSourceId());
                            deviceDetails2.setUpdatedOn(activeDevice.getUpdatedOn());
                            deviceDetails2.setAddedOn(activeDevice.getAddedOn());
                            activeDevicesRepo.save(deviceDetails2).subscribe(deviceDetails3 -> {
                                logger.info("Record updated Successfully...{}", deviceDetails3);
                                responseDTO.setResponseMessage("Updated Successfully");
                                responseDTO.setStatusCode(201);
                                return Mono.just(responseDTO);
                            });
                            
                        });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the usage of flatMap within the forEach loop. The flatMap operation is used to transform a value and unwrap it from a Mono or Flux. However, in your current code, you are using flatMap within a forEach loop, which does not allow you to return a Mono from inside the forEach loop. You are instead returning values from within the inner subscribe block, which doesn't work as expected.

Here's a modified version of your saveDeviceDetails method that uses Flux and flatMap correctly to handle the asynchronous operations and compose the final response:

```
@Override
public Mono<UserEventsResponseDTO> saveDeviceDetails(List<SelectedEventsForActiveDevicesWithDiscountDTO> deviceList) {
// ... (previous code)

// Process the list of device details using Flux
return Flux.fromIterable(activeDeviceList)
        .flatMap(activeDevice -> {
            String addedOnDate = activeDevice.getAddedOn().split("T")[0];
            String updatedOnDate = activeDevice.getUpdatedOn().split("T")[0];
            LocalDate addedOn = LocalDate.parse(addedOnDate);
            LocalDate updatedOn = LocalDate.parse(updatedOnDate);
            String deviceId = activeDevice.getDeviceId();

            if (!addedOn.isEqual(updatedOn)) {
                return activeDevicesRepo.findByDeviceIdAndAddedOn(deviceId, activeDevice.getAddedOn())
                        .flatMap(deviceDetails2 -> {
                            // Update device details and save
                            deviceDetails2.setContractId(activeDevice.getContractId());
                            deviceDetails2.setCustomerId(activeDevice.getCustomerId());
                            // ... (set other properties)
                            
                            return activeDevicesRepo.save(deviceDetails2)
                                    .map(savedDeviceDetails -> {
                                        responseDTO.setResponseMessage("Updated Successfully");
                                        responseDTO.setStatusCode(201);
                                        return responseDTO;
                                    });
                        });
            } else {
                // Handle the case where addedOn is equal to updatedOn
                // (You might want to return an appropriate response here)
                return Mono.empty();
            }
        })
        .last()  // Collect the last emitted value (responseDTO) from the Flux
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
            responseDTO.setResponseMessage("No records updated");
            responseDTO.setStatusCode(200);
            return Mono.just(responseDTO);
        }));
}
```

Comment: did you use chatgpt or any similar AI at all to write any part of this answer?